# Why did Mohammed Ali's coffin have cloth draped over it?

Tags: funeral

I've just seen @BBCBreaking's [Tweet](https://twitter.com/BBCBreaking/status/741276799586312194).

In it you can see Muhammad Ali's coffin with a cloth covering it that looks like Arabic writing and Allah's name on it. Perhaps it's the Shahada?

Why is this? Is it cultural? I've not seen it at any burial I've been to,  in the UK.

Answer (score -1):

All Praise to Allah Subhanahu wa Taala and blessings of Him be on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions

> Ibn Abbas narrated: "A red velvet cloth was placed in the grave of the
>   Prophet."([Tirmidhi](http://www.sunnah.com/tirmidhi/10/84))

This is not cultural and Grave of Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him has been covered by the covering for years,Some other prophets graves and Awlia graves are also covered by the sheets It is the way to show reverence too ,,see the inside view of Roza Rasool peace be upon him and green covering.

[image]

> Ja'far bin Muhammad narrated that: His father said: "The one who made
>   the Lahd in the grave of the Messenger of Allah was Abu Talhah. And
>   the one who placed the velvet cloth under him was Shuqran a freed
>   slave of Messenger of Allah."([Tirmidhi](http://www.sunnah.com/tirmidhi/10/83))

It is mentioned in Raddul Mukhtar that is allowed to put the cloth on the grave of a wali or pious person so people are more respectful when vsiting.

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.

Comment: Can you please reffer to anything about the question being asked, which is having such clothing which have quranic verses and things like that written on them, and is placed on dead person, or in grave. The reference you quoted from tirmidhi is just about placing a clothing under the dead in the Lahd, and question is not baout that type of clothing. Jazakallah

Answer (score -2):

### All perfect praise be to Allah

Brother **this kind of clothing, which has quranic verses written on it, sometimes durood and other things like shahadah too, these kind of clothing are not part of islamic teachings for burial.**

Many scholars, and even if i think of it, i will consider it wrong in many ways, to put quranic verses like this on a cloth and put on a dead man. And **many schools of thought don't allow any such clothing.**

But **some schools of thought do ALLOW them**.

Anyhow, this kind of clothing on dead people is not part of any islamic teaching, it is just an innovation(biddah) in islam, some may consider it bad innovation hence haraam, and some may say it is permissible innovation.

*I think this is enough for the answer of your question, for details of difference of opinion on biddah of this kind, you can look around on this site or just search about it.*

### Allah knows best

Comment: This really does nothing to answer the question asked: You seem more concerned with explaining why you think it should be forbidden (which is not what OP asked, and not what this site is for), and spend no time at all explain why it's done in the first place.

Comment: I put both the views and question was about if this is islamic or not, i gave the answer i knew. If you have better answer please post.

Comment: @goldPseudo because this answerer thinks they're is no valid reasoning they've explained why not. That's good enough for me.